# Extracting html table into panda DataFrame using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to read an html table and then extract it into pd.DataFrame but instead getting something different. What am I doing wrong?

the error is: [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38159852443c19167a9033a2b078fe45", element="ef6a42a1-2775-44c1-955f-5f01870bc758")>]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'mypath/chromedriver.exe', options = options) 
driver.get("https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Close']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@name='MCSearch'])[2]"))).send_keys('1818437')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@name='search'])[2]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='BASICs']/p[2]/a"))).click()
tables=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="BASICs"]/table/tbody/tr[2]')))
print(tables)
```

Disregard the bunch of extra imports as I've been trying to approach the problem in different way but keep failing

Answer (score 0):

I might have solved it, actually.

I changed the XPATH of the table from

```
'//*[@id="BASICs"]/table/tbody/tr[2]'
```

to

```
"//tr[@class='valueRow sumData']"
```

and I just realized I was printing the element and not its content so I changed the last line from
`print(tables)` to `print(tables.text)`

Now it's printing the table but for some reason it's not printing the very last value (0.05 in this case). Any ideas why?